# Prevent mat-datepicker from closing on date selection

Tags: angular, datepicker, mat-datepicker

I have a requirement that user can select multiple dates in datepicker, but after each date selection the mat-datepicker closes, I want to prevent mat-datepicker from closing on date selection and close the datepicker when we click outside the datepicker or on calendar icon.

[image: datepicker]

I tried `closed` event on mat-datepicker but the date-picker is flickering on each date selection plus it is doesn't close when we click outside the datepicker.

Here's what I tried:

html code:

```
<input formControlName="fromDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="fromDatePicker" placeholder="From Date" [min]="minDate" readonly>
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="fromDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #fromDatePicker (closed)="_openCalendar(fromDatePicker)"></mat-datepicker>
```

typescript code:

```
_openCalendar(picker: MatDatepicker<Date>) {
    picker.open();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59133977/multiple-date-select-in-material-datepicker-angular

Answer (score 4):

The way I prevented the overlay to close was to change **MatCalendar._userSelected** method.

If you look into the template of MatDatePickerContent, you would notice the call for when *_userSelection* is emitting. The call is to close the overlay: `(_userSelection)="datepicker.close()"`.
Now, *_userSelection* is emitting in **MatCalendar._userSelected**.

datepicker.js, line 1687, "@angular/material": "8.2.3":

```
_userSelected() {
    this._userSelection.emit();
}
```

Because I did not wanted this behaviour for all the instances of DatePicker in the application, in my component I did as follow:

```
@ViewChild('picker', { static: true }) 
private picker: MatDatepicker<Date>;
private preventCloseOnSelection = true;
private readonly initCalendarUserSelected: () => void;
public model: Array<Date>;

constructor(private readonly cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.initCalendarUserSelected = MatCalendar.prototype._userSelected;
}

public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.picker.calendarHeaderComponent = CalendarTimeHeaderComponent;

    this.picker.openedStream
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.isUnsubscribing))
        .subscribe(() => {

            if (this.preventCloseOnSelection) {
                MatCalendar.prototype._userSelected = () => {};
            } else {
                MatCalendar.prototype._userSelected = this.initCalendarUserSelected;
            }

            this.cdr.detectChanges();
        });
}

public ngOnDestroy() {
    MatCalendar.prototype._userSelected = this.initCalendarUserSelected;
}
```

If you want this behaviour for all the instances of date picker, you can override the *MatCalendar._userSelected* method somewhere in *AppComponent* and not bother to restore it.

One other way would be to do `this.picker.close = () => { };` after the date is changed, but you have to restore it always to be able to close the overlay.

You can get the selected date with the *dateChange* event of the *matDatepickerInput* and create an array with dates for multiple values and for having them selected in the view, you can use the *dateClass* input of the *matDatepicker*.

View:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="model" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" (dateChange)="dateChanged($event)" />
<mat-datepicker-toggle matPrefix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker [dateClass]="dateClass"></mat-datepicker>
```

Methods:

```
public dateClass = (date: Date) => {
    if (this.model.map((m) => +m).indexOf(+date) !== -1) {
        return [ 'selected' ];
    }
    return [ ];
}

public dateChanged(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    if (event.value) {
        const date = event.value;
        const index = this.model.map((m) => +m).indexOf(+date);
        if (index === -1) {
            this.model.push(date);
        } else {
            this.model.splice(index, 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like MatCalendar.prototype._userSelected does not exist on Angular 10 or 11

Answer (score 0):

in the case of the date range picker I solved this problem like below:

```
export class MatDatetimeComponent {
  @ViewChild(MatDateRangePicker) containerElRef;

  constructor(
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private cdkConnectedOverlay: OverlayOutsideClickDispatcher
  ) {}

  // store prototype close object
  private selfClose: () => void;

  ngAfterViewInit() { 
    this.selfClose = this.containerElRef.close;
  }
  public onOpen() { 
    // rewrite autoclose after date is chosen
    this.containerElRef.close = () => {};

    // close calendar manually on outside click
    this.cdkConnectedOverlay._attachedOverlays[0]._outsidePointerEvents.subscribe(() => {
        // restore saved close method
        this.containerElRef.close = this.selfClose;
        this.containerElRef.close();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the other Solutions did not work for me, I did this:

Typescript Code:

```
  @ViewChild(MatDatepicker) datePicker: MatDatepicker<Date>;

  constructor(
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private cdkConnectedOverlay: OverlayOutsideClickDispatcher) { }

  // store prototype close object
  private selfClose: () => void;

  opened() {
    if (isNullOrUndefined(this.selfClose)) {
      this.selfClose = this.datePicker.close;
    }

    // rewrite autoclose after date is chosen
    this.datePicker.close = () => {};

    // close calendar manually on outside click
    this.cdkConnectedOverlay._attachedOverlays[0]._outsidePointerEvents.subscribe(() => {
      // restore saved close method
      this.datePicker.close = this.selfClose;
      this.selfClose = undefined;
      this.datePicker.close();
    });
  }
```

Schema code:

```
  <mat-datepicker #picker
                  (opened)="opened()"
  ></mat-datepicker>
```

Maybe this can help someone out there.