# Is there a way to customize angular date picker?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I need help in customizing the angular material date picker i.e,https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview.
The calendar should not close once we click on the date. I should be able to have 2 buttons, one is 'cancel' and another is 'save'. Once the save button is clicked, the calendar should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's a better solution, but based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59133977/multiple-date-select-in-material-datepicker-angular/59136402#59136402), I think that the solution is use a menu with a calendar inside.

As we need an input we need at least two functions, one to parse the value of the input to a Date Object, and another to format the value of the input when we has a Date Object.

As I want this "special" datepicker can format the date in severals ways, YYYY-MM-DD and DD/MM/YYYY I need tree variables

```
  placeHolder:string="DD/MM/YYYY"
  separator:string;
  order:number[]=[];
```

A function give us the value of "separator and order"

```
  init(placeholder:string)
  {
     this.separator=placeholder.replace(/[YMD]/g,'').substr(0,1)
     const parts=placeholder.replace(/[.\/]/g,'-').split('-')
     this.order[0]=parts.indexOf('YYYY')
     this.order[1]=parts.indexOf('MM')
     this.order[2]=parts.indexOf('DD')
  }
```

So, our function parse and formats becomes like

```
format(date:any)
  {
    if (!date)
      return null;
    const parts=[''+date.getFullYear(),
                 ("00" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
                 ("00" + date.getDate()).slice(-2)]
    return parts[this.order[0]]+this.separator+
           parts[this.order[1]]+this.separator+
           parts[this.order[2]]
  }
  parse(value:string)
  {
   const parts=value?value.replace(/[.\/]/g,'-').split('-'):[]
   const date:any=(parts.length==3)?
        new Date(parts[this.order[0]]+'-'+parts[this.order[1]]+'-'+parts[this.order[2]]):
        null
   return date && date.getTime && date.getTime()?date:null
  }
```

An auxiliar function aloow us in (blur) reformatear the value

```
  tryFormat(value:string)
  {
    const date=this.parse(value)
    this.date=date?this.format(date):value
  }
```

And a function when the "menu" is open, allow change the active date of the calendar that get in a ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('calendar',{static:false}) calendar:any
onOpen()
  {
    if (this.date)
    {
      const date=this.parse(this.date);
      if (date)
      {
        this.calendar.activeDate=date;
      }
    }
  }
```

Finally, the .html is like

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="{{placeHolder}}" [(ngModel)]="date" (blur)="tryFormat(date)" >
    <button matSuffix mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu" (menuOpened)="onOpen()">
  <mat-icon>calendar_today</mat-icon>
</button>
  </mat-form-field>

<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu" class="drop-calendar" >
    <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
        <mat-calendar #calendar 
          (selectedChange)="date=format($event)" 
           [selected]="parse(date)">
        </mat-calendar>
    </div>
</mat-menu>
```

And the full code is in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-32fsyf-sfpdby?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the solution I was looking for :)