# Angular add toggle switch inside datepicker calendar

Tags: html, css, angular

Is it possible to add the toggle switch inside the calender? I want to put it at the top of the calender when the calendar is open so the user can choose to show date details by the toggle switch

```
<form #uploadForm="ngForm" (keydown.enter)="$event.preventDefault()">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        id="date"
        name="date"
        [disabled]="datePickerDisabled || uploadForm.submitted"
        [matDatepicker]="datepicker"
        placeholder="Expiration date"
        autocomplete="off"
        matInput
        required />
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker touchUi #datepicker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class="tooltip">This field is required.</div>
    <mat-slide-toggle
      (change)="setMaxExpirationDate($event)">Show Date Details</mat-slide-toggle>  
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you has two aproachs

1.-Customize the header, see the docs:[customizing header](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-calendar-header)

From this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57510066/how-can-i-catch-the-material-datepicker-month-pagination-event/57523930#57523930). replicate the header:

```
/** Custom header component for datepicker. */
@Component({
  selector: 'example-header',
  template: `
<mat-slide-toggle
      (change)="setMaxExpirationDate($event)">Show Date Details</mat-slide-toggle> 
  <div class="mat-calendar-controls">
    <button mat-button type="button" class="mat-calendar-period-button"
            (click)="currentPeriodClicked()" [attr.aria-label]="periodButtonLabel"
            cdkAriaLive="polite">
      {{periodButtonText}}
      <div class="mat-calendar-arrow"
           [class.mat-calendar-invert]="calendar.currentView != 'month'"></div>
    </button>

    <div class="mat-calendar-spacer"></div>

    <ng-content></ng-content>

    <button mat-icon-button type="button" class="mat-calendar-previous-button"
            [disabled]="!previousEnabled()" (click)="previousClicked()"
            [attr.aria-label]="prevButtonLabel">
    </button>

    <button mat-icon-button type="button" class="mat-calendar-next-button"
            [disabled]="!nextEnabled()" (click)="nextClicked()"
            [attr.aria-label]="nextButtonLabel">
    </button>
  </div>
</div>  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ExampleHeader extends MatCalendarHeader<any> {

  /** Handles user clicks on the period label. */
  currentPeriodClicked(): void {
    this.calendar.currentView = this.calendar.currentView == 'month' ? 'multi-year' : 'month';
  }
}
```

(change the .html to add the controls you want)

2.-Enclose the mat-datepicker in a mat-menu, like it showed in [this another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202061/is-there-a-way-to-customize-angular-date-picker/60205304#60205304)

**Updated** Access to an element of header it's not very easy. but control the toogle in easy if we use an intermediate service
Imagine you has a service like

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class CalendarService {
  private _event = new Subject<void>();
  public onEvent = this._event as Observable<any>;
  constructor() {}

  command(value: any) {
    this._event.next(value);
  }
}
```

You can inject the service in the constructor of customHeader

```
constructor(
    private _calendar: MatCalendar<D>,
    private _dateAdapter: DateAdapter<D>,
    @Inject(MAT_DATE_FORMATS) private _dateFormats: MatDateFormats,
    cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private service: CalendarService
  )
```

Then, if our toogle call a function

```
<mat-slide-toggle #toogle (change)="toogleChange($event)">
    Show Date Details
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

The function becomes like

```
  toogleChange(event: any) {
    this.service.command(event);
  }
```

Just in ngOnInit in the component subscribe to the service

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.onEvent.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res.checked);
    });
  }
```

You can see in [stackblitz](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Angular%20get%20parent%20component)

Comment: Do you know why this.slideToggle is undefined on the ngInit?

Comment: I suppose you has problem to control the toogle. After think about this, the best solution I find is use an intermediate service, see my updated answer

Comment: Excellent explanation