# How to show angular date picker without showing the input field

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

By Clicking calendar icon, need to open calendar in same position. But when remove the the input field the popup open in the top left on the page. How to fix it

Expected result
[image: type]

Comment: If you don't need a input, you can you can enclosed in a mat menu. In this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59133977/multiple-date-select-in-material-datepicker-angular/59136402#59136402 I used to create a "multi-select-date", but the idea is the same

Answer (score 0):

As i figured out, date picker position determine by the input field. So we can't simple hide the input field using none of below.

```
hidden = true | display:none | *ngIf = false
```

But we can do a hack for this one.

and a simple class to set the font size to 0px and make sure the icon and the input field in `display:inline-block`

Hope i helped for someone!