# How can we change the UI for dropdowns for mat-select?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to implement a dropdown, that would have a header with 3 columns(ID, Model, Description).
I know how to do a simple dropdown using mat-select,

```
 <mat-select>
    <mat-option> a </mat-option>
    <mat-option> b </mat-option>
    <mat-option> c </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

However, I got no clues on how to make a more complex dropdown,
Can someone give me a direction on how to approach this?
Thank you!
[Click the arrow, the dropdown will show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLMyo.jpg)

Comment: You supply a link to a hand drawn dropdown, no code, very little to go on, and you ask for a *hint*. Here's a hint: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Hi Richard, I did not mean to provide no codes, but I do not even know how to start to implement a customized dropdown. That's why I am asking fo a direction on how to approach it .

Answer (score 1):

it's not an "easy", Some time ago I made some like you want but using ng-bootstrap as base (it's is [this github](https://github.com/EliseoPlunker/customControl/tree/master/custom-lib/src/lib/drop-down-table) ). Making using material angular need the use of

1. a Mat-Input (read only)
2. a Mat-Menu (to simulate the "dropdown") -really I don't know why
   material angular has no a dropdown-
3. a Mat table

So you need some like

```
<input matInput (focus)="..." (blur)="..." (keydown)="...">
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    ...
    </table>
</mat-menu>
```

Good luck and happy coding!

NOTE: if we need that a matmenu don't close you can use some like [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59133977/multiple-date-select-in-material-datepicker-angular/59136402#59136402)

```
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
    <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
        ..here what you want..
    </div>
</mat-menu>
```