# How to set a multi select calendar with Material Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, calendar, multi-select

I have a Calendar but i can only set one date and i want to be able to set multiple dates. I dont see anything in the official documentation (https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) and i´m stuck.

[image]

My code is that

Ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-inline-calendar-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-inline-calendar-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-inline-calendar-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerInlineCalendarExample {
  selected: Date | null;
}
```

And the HTML

```
<mat-card class="demo-inline-calendar-card">
  <mat-calendar [(selected)]="selected"></mat-calendar>
</mat-card>
<p>Selected date: {{selected}}</p>
```

In the HTML i can set range picker but i dont know how todo multiple select dates. Thanks

Comment: it's a bit old, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59133977/multiple-date-select-in-material-datepicker-angular/59136402#59136402

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Date range selection using, e.g. (like mentioned in the docs):

```html
 <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
  <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
  <input matEndDate placeholder="End date">
</mat-date-range-input>
<mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I had exact same problem.

HTML:

```
<mat-calendar [selected]="selectedRangeValue"
  (selectedChange)="selectedChange($event)">
</mat-calendar>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { DateRange } from '@angular/material/datepicker';

@Component({
    selector: 'inline-range-calendar',
    templateUrl: './inline-range-calendar.component.html',
})
export class InlineRangeCalendarComponent {

    @Input() selectedRangeValue: DateRange<Date> | undefined;
    @Output() selectedRangeValueChange = new EventEmitter<DateRange<Date>>();

    selectedChange(m: any) {
        if (!this.selectedRangeValue?.start || this.selectedRangeValue?.end) {
            this.selectedRangeValue = new DateRange<Date>(m, null);
        } else {
            const start = this.selectedRangeValue.start;
            const end = m;
            if (end < start) {
                this.selectedRangeValue = new DateRange<Date>(end, start);
            } else {
                this.selectedRangeValue = new DateRange<Date>(start, end);
            }
        }
        this.selectedRangeValueChange.emit(this.selectedRangeValue);
    }

}
```